# SiteCatalyst count clicks on button

Tags: jquery, tracking

I would like to use SiteCatalyst and jQuery to count the number of clicks on a button. I have been given  en event (event98) to use for the collection of clicks. I found this snippet:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btn').live("click", function(){
    s=s_gi('myRSID');
    s.events='event98';
    s.t(this,'o','My title')
    });
    });
</script>
```

The button looks like this:

```
<input id="btn" type="button" value="Submit" />
```

but somehow I don't get any clicks in my report. (I did change myRSID to the correct id when testing.)

Is the above code correct for tracking button clicks?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you want to use (notice the s.tl rather than s.t)

```
s.tl(this,'o','My title')
```

There is a nice set of articles I found about this aspect as I was looking into this myself
http://www.marketingoptimizations.com/adobe-sitecatalyst-s-tl-pros-and-cons/

Answer (score -1):

your problem could be that you do not populate the variables 
s.trackingServer
s.trackingServerSecure
s.dc

If you create a new s object in the event listener you should populate them with the correct value (you can find them in the s_code.js).

The 3 variables are used to decide to which datacenter send the call, if the datacenter is wrong the call is just lost.

Bye,
Claudio.